# Configure Sendmail To Not Be Authoritative

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail

On Ubuntu 16 I have sendmail installed.

The server is also a webserver, hosting files for mysite.com
The server's hostname (/etc/hostname) is mysite.com.

This server is not intended to receive any email of any kind. But I would like to send mail from it. I want to send mail from this server to users on the same domain.

someuser@mysite.com

These users exist on an exchange server that the company I work for manages.

My issue is, when I try to send email (via sendmail) from my server to another user on the same domain as my hostname, it can't get out. The server knows that itself is mysite.com, and is capturing emails going to someone@mysite.com.

When I run sendmail in debugging and check the 'w' class: "sendmail -bt" then "$=w", clear as day, mysite.com is listed as one of the domains for which sendmail should intercept email.

I have emptied out the local-host-names file.

I have created a relay-domains file with mysite.com and empty. Neither made any difference.

I have tried adding define(`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES',`True') to sendmail.mc.

I have tried adding FEATURE(relay_entire_domain)dnl to sendmail.mc

I have made sure that no "LOCAL_DOMAIN" directives exist in my sendmial.mc.

I have edited sendmail.cf (the generated file), uncommented the "Dj" directive and made it "Djsomething.mysite.com". This makes that domain show up in $=w, but still doesn't eliminate mysite.com.

The steps above seem to add more entries to my $=w, but they never eliminate the exist mysite.com entry that it got from my hostname.

I know to use sudo sendmailconfig when I edit my sendmail.mc file
I'm also needlessly restarting the sendmail service even though sendmailconfig reloads.

I need some way to either:

1. Make sendmail stop answering to mysite.com
   Or
2. Make sendmail not know that it is mysite.com

An acceptable answer is not to change my hostname. Please don't suggest that.

Thank you guys

EDIT:

Running the following command, produces the following output:

```
grep -Ei '^(Dj|Fw|Cw|O DontProbe)' /etc/mail/sendmail.cf

Cwlocalhost
Fw/etc/mail/local-host-names %[^\#]
Djcoolsubdomain.mysite.com
O DontProbeInterfaces=True
```

Comment: This might be a better question for [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se]. Consider deleting this and posting on one of those sites.

Comment: Could you include results produced by `grep -Ei '^(Dj|Fw|Cw|O DontProbe)' /etc/mail/sendmail.cf`?

Comment: I have updated my question to include the results of that command. I changed the subdomain and domain to be fake obviously. Rather the whole world not know the company.